# How to check if variable is null, but allow 1 and 0?

Tags: javascript

I use the following code currently

```
if (oldValue) ...
```

It works well in case `oldValue` is `null`, but in case it is 0, it also returns `false`, when I expect `true`. So, how should I check for `null` value? I was thinking about

```
if (oldValue!=null) ...
```

but it doesn't work as I've expected.

Comment: Why does `oldValue != null` not work as expected? What does it do and what do you expect? What are possible values for `oldValue`?

Comment: If you want a truthy evaluation of `0`, then `!= null` will give you that.

Comment: Which values do you want to accept as 'true' and which as 'false'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question directly, if your allowed values are `0` and `1` the `if` statement should look like:

```
if (0 === oldValue || 1 === oldValue) {
     ...
}
```

This is (in my opinion) the clearest way to state which values are allowed.

For a more details explanation see below:

---

This has to do with **truthy** and **falsy** values.

`null` evaluates to `false`, as do `0`, `""`, `undefined` and `NaN`, these are called **falsy** values.

Likewise, some values evaluate to `true`. Such as: `"a string"`, `"0"` (non empty string "0"), any number other than `0` (including negative numbers), `Array`s and `Object`s (even empty ones). These are **truthy** values.

There are some unexpected results:

```
"" == false     // true
0 == false      // true
```

but:

```
NaN == false    // false
null == false   // false
```

In practice you should always use the identity operator `===` instead of equality (`==`). This ensures that you know what type your variable is expected to be (String, Number, Object) and what the exceptional states are.

Some examples:

- If you're getting a value from an input field it will always be a string - the special case is the empty string. Coincidentally this is a **falsy** value.
- If you're counting elements and you need to do something special in case there are no elements - the special case is `0`. Coincidentally this is a **falsy** value.
- If you're trying to parse a number from a string using `parseInt` or `parseFloat` - the special case `NaN` (check with `isNaN()`). Coincidentally this is a **falsy** value.
- If you're checking if a substring occurs within a string using `indexOf` - the special case is `-1` (because `0` is a valid index). This is **not** a **falsy** value, but `if(str.indexOf(substr))` is most certainly wrong because it is unclear the author knows about the possibly allowed value `0` (which *is* **falsy**)

The point here is: the special cases usually are well defined. Harnessing that allows you to always use the identity operator `===`. *The equality operator `==` and falsiness is a common source of bugs.*

For reference:

```
"" === false    // false
0 === false     // false
NaN === false   // false
null === false  // false
false === false // true (of course)
NaN === NaN     // strange, but makes sense
"a" === "a"     // yay!
```

Comment: -1 For linking to a different site in lieu of actually answering the question here. If you decide to answer, I'll remove the vote.

Comment: Hmm, what happened to all the other answers? I was merely posting them as reference. But I'll update my question.

Comment: The other answers self-deleted because they realized that the question doesn't make sense. The last line of code posted in the question already meets OP's needs.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: If you want to test exactly whether the variable does not have the value `null`, then change your code to:

```
if (oldValue !== null) ...
```

(However, you should think about whether the `oldValue` might be `undefined` rather than `null`, which would have to be a separate case.)

See [Frits van Campen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549696/how-to-check-if-variable-is-null-but-allow-1-and-0/9549719#9549719) for the details of the difference between `==`/`!=` and `===`/`!==`.